# best practices of implementing encryption and decryption in C#

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, encryption

Kindly share best practices of implementing encryption and decryption in C#.

Please refer some coad if possible.

Comment: The primary "best practice" is to use what's in the library, and avoid doing it yourself at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following link for information and samples:

[Symmetric and Asymmetric encryption](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SimpleEncryption.aspx)